# OSMNX: Length of Street edges

Tags: python, openstreetmap, osmnx

I'm trying to get a list of edge lengths, and plot a graph coloring the edges per length category.
I couldn't find out how to access this attribute.

when I check:

```
edge_attributes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False).columns
print(edge_attributes)
```

I get the following:

```
runfile('C:/Users/user/.spyder-py3/temp.py', wdir='C:/Users/user/.spyder- 
py3')
Index(['u', 'v', 'key', 'osmid', 'highway', 'oneway', 'name', 'length',
'geometry', 'maxspeed', 'lanes', 'tunnel', 'service', 'access'],
dtype='object')
```

So it looks like there is an attribute called length, which I was not able to access to.

Would love to get some support.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

### Retrieve edge information from the graph as a geodataframe

```
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=False, edges=True)
edges_series = edges['length'] #gives you a pandas series with edge lengths
edges[['osmid','length']] #gives you a pandas dataframe with osmids of edges and their corresponding lengths
```

### For plotting graph with edge colours, OSMnx has a dedicated function

```
ec = ox.get_edge_colors_by_attr(G, attr='length')
ox.plot_graph(G, edge_color=ec)
```